# Message level security and signing in SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federated-identity

I have a general question about keys used in SAML federations.

Normally to establish an SSO, the XML messages and SAML assertions are signed by one partner (IdP or SP).

Normally which partner should sign the message with the private key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender of a message is the one that signs it.

A common message exchange using the SAML2 WebSSO profile is:

1. The SP (Service Provider) sends an `AuthnRequest` to the Idp. The `AuhtnRequest` might be signed by the SP, but doesn't have to.
2. The Idp (Identity Provider) sends a `SamlResponse` back to the SP through a HTTP POST. The Idp might sigh the entire SamlResponse or only the contained Assertion(s) or both. If the SamlResponse is not signed, the Assertions must be signed to be trusted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still new to this so kind of confused.
What if user first landed on the ldp site and get authenticated at the ldp site and click on a link to access the SP site. Does ldp sign the assertion and send it to SP? Does SP still send AuthRequest?

Comment: That scenario is called "unsolicited response". Step 1 is omitted. The Idp sends a response without having received a request. The Response/Assertion(s) are still signed by the Idp.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. So can I say regardless of AuthRequest from SP or unsolicited response, is best practice or more common for the ldp to sign the assertion?

Comment: The Idp ALWAYS signs the assertion, including for unsolicited responses.